# Why is $\sqrt [n] 1$ not an expression "in radicals" of a root of unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, notation, roots-of-unity

In Edwards' Galois Theory, in the chapter on Cyclotomic polynomials, the author devotes a lot of effort to proving that prime order primitive roots of unity can be expressed "by radicals", and gives the example:

$$\sqrt[3] 1 = \frac {-1 \pm \sqrt {-3}} {2}$$

While I agree that this expresses $\sqrt[3] 1$ using radicals, isn't $\sqrt[3] 1$ *already* such an expression?

Comment: No. $\sqrt[3]{1}=1$.

Comment: I'd say "Yes, $\root 3\of 1=1$".

Comment: @MattSamuel The notation $\sqrt [3] 1$ is ambiguous. It could just as well refer to *any* cube root of unity. And if you don't want any ambiguous expressions, then you can't even write $\sqrt{-3}$ in the above expression, because that's ambiguous too.

Comment: @JackM No, it isn't ambiguous. For real numbers $a$, $\sqrt[3]{a}$ denotes exactly one number.

Comment: @JackM Nor is $\sqrt{-3}$ ambiguous. $\sqrt{-3}=i\sqrt{3}$. Even though $-i\sqrt{3}$ is also a square root, it is not equal to $\sqrt{-3}$.

Comment: Okay, well what it boils down to is: what is the precise definition of "a radical expression" which rules out $\sqrt [3] 1$ yet includes the expression in the question?

Comment: @JackM Excellent remark. This is why (despite what self-declared opponents of political correctness pretend on this page) $\sqrt{\ }$ is not defined on $\mathbb C$ or on $\mathbb R$ either, only on $\mathbb R_+$.

Comment: @Did So are you saying that $\sqrt{-1}$ is not well defined? It is well defined. It is $i$. $\sqrt$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why is it i and not -i?

Comment: @Tryss Because that's the way it is defined.

Comment: So there is no problem to "define" $\sqrt[n]{\cdot}$ on the whole of $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: @Tryss Notice that I did not say $\mathbb{C}$. I said $\mathbb{R}$. Seriously, are you playing devil's advocate or something?

Comment: @Tryss And if you look at my answer, I say that $\sqrt[n]{\cdot}$ is defined only for positive real numbers, but the square root is defined for all real numbers. $i$ is the principal square root of $-1$.

Comment: But there is indeed no problem to define $\sqrt[n]{z}$ : the number $a\in \mathbb{C}$ that verify $a^n = z$ with the smallest possible argument (in $[0,2\pi[$). Notice that it's totally compatible with your definition

Comment: @Tryss That is true.

Comment: @MattSamuel Yes $\sqrt{-1}$ is not well defined because there is no way to define a nice function $f$ on $\mathbb C$ such that $f(z)^2=z$ for every $z$ and because there is no practical advantage to manipulate (the ill-defined) $\sqrt{-1}$ rather than (the perfectly rigorous) $i$.

Comment: ((Judging by the several exhausting discussions on the site about this subject, there must be a problem with the way roots are taught in the only educational system known to quite a few users here.))

Comment: @Did $\sqrt{x}$ does not mean "the number whose square is $x$." This is a common mistake that I see in elementary questions on this site. Just as $\arcsin(x)$ does not mean "the number whose sine is $x$."

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a good question.

Roots of unity are special - they are units of finite multiplicative order. It is sometimes necessary to know whether your context has "enough" (or "the right") roots of unity, so knowing their properties in terms of potentially more primitive concepts does help. Knowing when extensions by radicals include roots of unity can be very valuable. The key question is more about which radical extensions contain which roots of unity than whether roots of unity are themselves radical.

As an example of how we can get in a mess, we have $i^4=1$, but if you write $\sqrt[3]1=\frac {-1\pm i\sqrt 3}2$ what allows you to use $i$ in the expression for $\sqrt[3]1$? $i$ is itself a radical expression over $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb Z$ (and the ground ring or field tends to matter a bit here).

Comment: Do you mean $i$ for the expression $\sqrt[4]{1}$? Because we can't use $i$ for $\sqrt[3]{1}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Correct. I thought I saw an $i$ in one of the posts or comments (I think there is still one there to avoid a $\sqrt {-3}$). My second paragraph is the main thing I wanted to say - I'll rearrange things accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

"The number $\alpha$ is expressed in terms of radicals" means that there is a chain:

$$F_n\supset F_{n-1}\supset\cdots\supset F_0=\mathbb Q$$

where there exists an irreducible polynomial $q_i(x)\in\mathbb F_{i-1}[x]$ of the form $q_i(x)=x^{n_i}-\alpha_i$ such that $F_i\cong F_{i-1}[x]/\langle q_i(x)\rangle$, and $\alpha\in F_n$.

That's a fairly technical definition, but the key word here is "irreducible." $x^3-1$ is not an irreducible polynomial.

Comment: Why the insistence that they be irreducible?

Comment: Ultimately, because Galois theory doesn't (obviously) let us do fun things with the field extensions when the polynomial is not irreducible. @JackM

Answer (score 0):

the meaning is not the number $1$, but all of the solutions to the equation $x^3-1=0$, or $x^n-1=0$ in the general case.

Comment: The trouble with this is that this amounts to defining $\sqrt[3]{1}$ as **a set**, not a number. Why not? But then, one should declare this clearly and one should realize that this forbids to think of $\sqrt[3]{1}$ as a number.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental theorem of algebra tells us that an expression like $x^3 - 1$ has three roots. But most of the time, when we write something like "$\root 3 \of 7$", we only want one root, a root that is in some way more "principal" than the others, such as, for example, being a purely real positive number. So some of us agree explicitly that $\root b \of a$ represents the principal $b$th root of $a$, while others don't even realize they're agreeing to this.

And so, just as $\root 3 \of 8$ means 2 and not $-1 + \sqrt{-3}$ nor $-1 + \sqrt{-3}$, $\root 3 \of 1$ means 1, and not $-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ nor $-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2}$. So 1 is its own principal cubic root, but the complex cubic roots are of course more interesting, which is why there is often the assignment $\omega = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ ($w$ is sometimes used, but it's a poor substitute, in my opinion).

---

It was pointed out in a comment that $\sqrt{-3}$ could be considered ambiguous. I suppose it is, unless we agree to the following definition: the principal square root of a negative real number is a positive imaginary number. So, the principal square root of $-3$ is approximately $\frac{433}{250}i$, and $-\frac{433}{250}i$ is the other root.